# Accessing managedObjectContext in initWithCoder:

Tags: cocoa, core-data, drag-and-drop, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am trying to implement drag and drop operations on `NSManagedObject` subclasses, among others using the information under "drag and drop" in Apple's doc https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001803-CJBDBHCB.

I have an NSManagedObject subclass called Person, and want to use its managedObjectID (URI-encoded) to perform a linking operation. The docs state the following method to recover my Person object from a URI-encoded moID on the pasteboard:

```
NSURL *moURL = // get it from the pasteboard ...
NSManagedObjectID *moID = [[managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator]
    managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:moURL];
// assume moID non-nil...
NSManagedObject *mo = [managedObjectContext objectWithID:moID];
```

How would I access the managedObjectContext? At the time I run this code (`initWithCoder:`), the value is still *nil*.

Answer (score 0):

Think of your Managed Object Context as a scratchpad. The link you posted explains it as:

> Simply modifying a managed object does not cause the changes to be saved to a store. The managed object context acts as a scratchpad. You can create and register managed objects with it, make changes to the objects, and undo and redo changes as you wish. If you make changes to managed objects associated with a given context, those changes remain local to that context until you commit the changes by sending the context a save: message

So you could use the same context that you use in other places. Let's assume you create a single context in the appDelegate by using the Apple Core Data Templates. This context becomes `managedObjectContext` in your code. You work with the `mo` object and at the end you `save:` the context or you do a `rollback`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The bottom line of my problem is that my app is document based, and I cannot talk about a single context. So, my managed object (that's being initialized) already needs to know which `managedObjectContext` it belongs to. Hmmm.